# Jcreator Error when running a file

Tags: java, ide, jcreator

Command   : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe" -classpath "C:\Users\Zachsta\Downloads;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar" 
Directory : C:\Users\Zachsta\Downloads

Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

Process completed.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't all go into the code section... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is more a question for the JCreator support team, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother your self for setting environment.
I had same problem and I was tired of it solving, this is very huge problem. Reason is you have to be known that Jcreator is working on x86 architecture, so you must install 32 bit Java Version, and in the configuration of Jcreator,
you must choose the path of 32 bit version of Java as -->
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66 )
Any time you may get this error so make sure to check the path of Java in Config of Jcreator.
My problem solved, hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told Java to run anything - you just gave it a long classpath.

Append the name of the class with a `public static void main(String[])` to the command (i.e.: `java -classpath stuff MyClassWithMain`)

Also note that files inside the java lib folder do not need to be specified manually.